# Different result using wikiPageRedirects resource in DBPedia

Tags: redirect, rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have a question:

I want to retrieve the type of a certain page by making "rdf:type".
If my source is "London", I write this query:

```
prefix dbpediaont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select distinct ?mat where {
dbpedia:London rdf:type ?mat
}
```

I get this result:
[QUERY SPARQL](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbpediaont%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3Fmat%20where%20%7B%0D%0Adbpedia%3ALondon%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Fmat%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Now, if I use the resource "Leondeon", which is a resource redirection "London" (I see that it is present in "is dbpedia-owl: wikiPageRedirects of"), I do not get any results.

```
prefix dbpediaont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select distinct ?mat where {
dbpedia:Leondeon rdf:type ?mat
}
```

[QUERY SPARQL](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbpediaont%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3Fmat%20where%20%7B%0D%0Adbpedia%3ALeondeon%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Fmat%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

I thought that since "Leondeon" is a redirection of "London" (I interpret as if they were the same), I thought that any "rdf:type" of "Leondeon" give me same results as "London".
I wonder why I get a different result in this case, where the resources used belong to the same URI "http://dbpedia.org/resource/London".

Comment: As it stands your question is unclear and liable to get closed because problem because you haven't posted your raw SPARQL queries.  Since you are asking about why the results aren't as expected you should be including both the actual results and the expected results

Comment: This question already has an answer in the duplicate that I linked to.  There's a slight difference in that that question asks about `dbpedia-owl:type` rather than `rdf:type`, but it's easy to adjust: `dbpedia:Cupertino dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects*/dbpedia-owl:type ?type` becomes `dbpedia:Leondeon dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects*/rdf:type ?mat`.